# Animated gif stops for a moment before restarting in adobe photoshop

Tags: photoshop, animated-gif

I am trying to create a loading animated GIF img, but whenever it completes its one cycle it stops for a little moment and then restart,which means it doesn't have the same continuity.I dont want this little blinking thing. kindly help.
I am creating it in adobe Photoshop CC.

Comment: Pics or it didn't happen!

Answer (score 0):

Normally, this problem happens when the first and the last frame are the same, try removing one. Without more information is the only thing I can think of.